# Need to implement #cache! if you want to use Cloudinary::CarrierWave::Storage as a cache storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

I am getting this error when trying to upload a picture "Need to implement #cache! if you want to use Cloudinary::CarrierWave::Storage as a cache storage."
It highlights this part of code in my controller:

```
def update
  @company.update(company_params)
  redirect_to company_path(@company)
end
```

I am using Carrierwave to upload photo to cloudinary.
I have a cloudinary.yml file with my configuration as well as a cloudinary.rb in my initializers.

identitylogo_uploader.rb

```
class IdentitylogoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave


  process :convert => 'png'
  process :tags => ['logo_entreprise']

  version :standard do
    process :resize_to_fill => [150, 150, :north]
  end

  version :thumbnail do
    resize_to_fit(50, 50)
  end


  def public_id
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

---

company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :identitylogo, IdentitylogoUploader
end
```

---

companies_controller.erb

```
def update
  @company.update(company_params)
  redirect_to company_path(@company)
end

def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(:identitylogo, :name, :industry, 
  :employees, :website)
end
```

---

_form.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @company do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :industry %>
  <%= f.input :employees %>
  <%= f.input :website %>
  <%= f.input :identitylogo_cache, as: :hidden %>
  <%= f.input :identitylogo, label: false %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

_show.html.erb

```
<img src="<%= @company.identitylogo %> " alt="Logo de 
l'entreprise">
```

I noticed that the link is generated yet the file is not uploaded to cloudinary.

Comment: Update:

I changed the IdentitylogoUploader to add the storage line like this:

```storage :file```

The error is gone, the uploading ends but the picture is not uploaded to cloudinary! When I inspect in the browser I see the link (that takes you nowhere since there's no pic on the cloudinary) and when I check the DB I find the value for the photo like this:
`identitylogo: "uploads/company/identitylogo/127.png"> `

Comment: Cloudinary should be able to help with this directly too - you can open a request at https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/

Comment: @AyoubBenThabet did you have any luck finding a solution? I'm having a similar problem (but with Imagekit::Carrierwave instead of Cloudinary).

Comment: Opened an issue here https://github.com/imagekit-developer/imagekit-gem/issues/6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Added `config.cache_storage = :file` to carrierwave initializer and the error is gone.

```rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
 # For an application which utilizes multiple servers but does not need caches persisted across requests,
 # uncomment the line :file instead of the default :storage.  Otherwise, it will use the default storage as the temp cache store.
 config.cache_storage = :file
end
```

Here is the commit that change the old behavior : [link](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/commit/629afecbaeccd2300e4660b78ee36bd95dd845c5)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the newest version of CarrierWave is not compatible with Cloudinary yet.

Check your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock. I had to remove the .rc-ending and restart the server.